# Rules behind using news logos on websites

Tags: fair-use, false-advertising

I see many people on LinkedIn using the logo of news sites they were featured on or had a PR piece republished on. What are the US laws around the use of such logos?

What happens if someone falsely uses such logos to convey authority when they actually never were quoted or featured on that site? Is that false advertising?